# Vuejs - How to add multiple loading indicators (spinner) to have different states from each other?

Tags: vue.js

What I want is the spinner which can be found here in [How To Add Loading Indicators to Your Vue.js Application](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/add-loading-indicators-to-your-vuejs-application). However I want to use it for different elements and with different states. For example when the first image is uploading, I change the state of the spinner to be shown however if I change the variable `spinner` to true, all the spinners inside all images will be shown but I want only the spinner that its parent(image) is uploading to be circulating.

```
<div class="image">
    <input class="d-none" type="file" @change="spinner = true"> <!-- This shows other spinners too -->
    <div class="loader" v-if="spinner === true"></div>
</div>
<div class="image">
    <input class="d-none" type="file" @change="spinner = true"> <!-- This shows other spinners too -->
    <div class="loader" v-if="spinner === true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd have to assign something unique to `spinner`, an id of some sort then check if it equals like this: `v-if="spinner === uniqueId"`

Comment: Otherwise, `spinner` applies to all instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a component per each image with it's own state. Or another solution would be to put each image object (with state logic and name) in an array and loop through it with v-for, changing loading state in particular object. E.g.

```
<div class="image" v-for="(image, i) in images" :key="i">
    <input class="d-none" type="file" @change="image.loading = true"> 
    <div class="loader" v-if="image.loading"></div>
</div>

data() {
return {
 images: [
    {src: 'www/some.com', loading: false},
    {src: 'www/some2.com', loading: false} 
  ]
}}
```

Comment: That's right but what if I have hundred images or infinitive which is an array of image: `images[]`

Comment: Then I  would  create a component per each image with it's own state.

Comment: Or another solution would be to put each image object (with state logic and name) in an array and loop through it with v-for, changing loading state in particular object